# How to select rows from a dataframe were any value is not equal to a specified value

Tags: python, pandas

I've been able to filter Pandas dataframe rows containing a number:

```
import pandas as pd    

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [3, 1, 2], 'c2': [3, 3, 3], 'c3': [2, 5, None], 'c4': [1, 2, 3]})

   c1  c2   c3  c4
0   3   3  2.0   1
1   1   3  5.0   2
2   2   3  NaN   3

df1 = df[(df.values == 1)]

   c1  c2   c3  c4
0   3   3  2.0   1
1   1   3  5.0   2
```

But if I try to filter based excluding a number, I get a really strange result with repeated rows:

```
df1 = df[(df.values != 1)]

   c1  c2   c3  c4
0   3   3  2.0   1
0   3   3  2.0   1
0   3   3  2.0   1
1   1   3  5.0   2
1   1   3  5.0   2
1   1   3  5.0   2
2   2   3  NaN   3
2   2   3  NaN   3
2   2   3  NaN   3
2   2   3  NaN   3
```

Why is that? And how can I filter only the rows that don't contain the specified number?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at this mask

```
In [88]: df.values != 1
Out[88]:
array([[ True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Slicing base on numpy convention. Every `True` will be repeated, so you have repeated rows in the output. You need additional `all` to check each row on all `True` and return a single True/False for each row.

```
df[(df.values != 1).all(1)]

Out[87]:
   c1  c2  c3  c4
2   2   3 NaN   3
```

---

Note: my intention is reusing your code, so I didn't change it. While the concise code should be.

```
df[(df != 1).all(1)]
```

or

```
df[df.ne(1).all(1)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [DataFrame.any](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df[~df.eq(1).any(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   c1  c2  c3  c4
2   2   3 NaN   3
```

Comment: Or `df[(df.values != 1).all(1)]`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
indexes = [x for x in range(len(list(df.values))) if 1 not in df.values[x]] # get indexes where 1 not appear
df.iloc[indexes]
```

output:

```
    c1  c2  c3  c4
2   2   3   NaN 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, use the filter to create an index, reverse the index, and then select the rows based off that index.

```
import pandas as pd    

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [3, 1, 2,   1, 3], 
                   'c2': [3, 3, 3,   2, 3], 
                   'c3': [2, 5, None,3, 3], 
                   'c4': [1, 2, 3,   1, 3]})
print(df)
# Create an index based on any row containing 1
index = df.values == 1
print(index)
# This reverses the index. 
# I.e. 
#[False False False  True] will equal False, since True is in the list
#[True False False False]  will equal False, since True is in the list
#[False False False False] will equal True,  since True is NOT in the list
index = [True if True not in l else False for l in index]
# Pick out only the rows where the index is true
df1 = df[index]
print(df1)
```